# re-coding based on two columns to rest of columns using R

Tags: r, loops, dataset, format

I have big data, mini-version is like the follows:

```
    Pr1  <- c("AA", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "--", "AA", "--")
    Pr2  <- c("BB", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "--", "--", "BB")
    varA  <- c("BB", "AA", "AA", "BB", "BB", "AA", "--", "BB")
    varB  <- c("AA", "BB", "AA", "BB", "BB", "AA", "--", "BB")
    varC <- c("AB", "--", "AB", "BB", "AB", "AA", "--", "AB")
    varD <- c("BB", "AA", "AB", "BB", "BB", "AB", "AB", "BB")
     mydf <- data.frame (Pr1, Pr2, varA, varB, varC, varD)
```

The data looks like the follows:

```
     mydf 

   Pr1 Pr2 varA varB varC varD
1  AA  BB   BB   AA   AB   BB
2  BB  AA   AA   BB   --   AA
3  BB  AA   AA   AA   AB   AB
4  BB  AA   BB   BB   BB   BB
5  BB  AA   BB   BB   AB   BB
6  --  --   AA   AA   AA   AB
7  AA  --   --   --   --   AB

8  --  BB   BB   BB   AB   BB
```

I need to recode rest of variable in dataframe based on first two:

if elements of varA to varD (end of dataset) -

- is equal to Pr1 value than elements of varA to varD will be "A",
- is equal to Pr2 value than elements of varA to varD will be "B"
- is equal to neither Pr1 and Pr2 than  varA to varD will be "H"

however -- is missing value, the above rule do not apply in that case.

if either Pr1 and Pr2 are missing (--), then comparison result in "NA" for all value.

Thus expected result:

```
   Pr1 Pr2 varA varB varC varD
1  AA  BB   B    A    H    B
2  BB  AA   B    A   --    B
3  BB  AA   B    B    H    H
4  BB  AA   A    A    A    A
5  BB  AA   A    A    H    A
6  --  --   NA   NA   NA   NA
7  AA  --   NA   NA   NA   NA

8  --  BB   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

I could find a way to perform it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write a little function that just does it for 1 row, then apply it. I found it convenient to first convert to a matrix

```
    mymat <- as.matrix(mydf)
    recodeRows <- function(x){
        if (any(x[1:2]=="--")){
             x[3:ncol(mymat)] <- NA
        } else {
             x[3:ncol(mymat)][x[3:ncol(mymat)]==x[1]] <- "A"
             x[3:ncol(mymat)][x[3:ncol(mymat)]==x[2]] <- "B"
             x[3:ncol(mymat)][!x[3:ncol(mymat)] %in% c("A","B","--")] <- "H"
        }
    x
    }
    t(apply(mymat,1,recodeRows))
```

[Edited to include the ncol(mymat) comment from John]

Comment: use 3: ncol(mymat), where we have more than 6 columns (need not count

Answer (score 1):

You can save yourself some work when you pull in the data by setting:

`na.strings="--"` to automatically set "--" elements to `NA` also, you can set it up such that strings are not converted to factors. `as.is=TRUE`

See `?read.table`

These two settings mean you're now dealing with somethings that's not auto factored and has the NA's where it should.

And... as I'm writing this someone has already come up with a function so I'm going to stop there and you can consider this as an extended comment.